# verify chages in Initial congestion window

Tags: linux, cwnd

I am trying see the effects of changing Initial CWND of my server.This given [here](http://www.cdnplanet.com/blog/tune-tcp-initcwnd-for-optimum-performance/#change-initcwnd).To confirm this whether its changed to value I have set.I am referring [this](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/tcpprobe).But I am not able to see any changes.By default after linux 2.6.38 the default InitCWND is  10.Is there other way to verify the initcwnd? This post is also [here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7610/initial-congestion-window-change)

Answer (score 0):

If your server serves http then you can use this new tool : http://www.cdnplanet.com/tools/initcwndcheck/

disclosure: Im author of that.